# mPDF: Rotate a barcode inside a table cell

Tags: css, html-table, orientation, barcode, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to generate PDF files containing event tickets. I'd like to display vertically oriented barcodes in a table cell on the edges of the tickets. I can't find a way to have the barcode image generated vertically using the [in-built barcode facility](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/barcodes.html), or to rotate the barcode via the [supported CSS options](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html). (I tried the text-rotate option on the table cell my barcodes were added to, but this only works when there is nothing other than text in the cell.)

Example use of the in-built barcode facility:

```
<barcode code="978-0-9542246-0" type="ISBN" class="barcode" height="0.66" text="1" />
```

I could use a third party barcode facility to embed these as images, but I'd prefer to use the native facility in mPDF if possible.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Show some code. How are you embedding the barcodes? Is it like <img src="mPDF.com/somethingsomething">?
What css options have you tried?
Looks like writing-mode vertical-lr doesn't work in chrome: https://crbug.com/409155 (writing-mode doesn't work on th or td elements)

Comment: mPDF does not rely on Chrome or any other browser. Links and example added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotated barcode at the bottom right corner of the page example:

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 0mm; bottom: 0mm; rotate: -90;">
    <barcode code="100101001" />
</div>
```

Comment: Only seeing this now. Haven't verified it, but looks like this should work. Accepting it